# Convert Generic Arraylist into an array with Generic Type

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I'm trying to use ArrayList's built in Java method that converts an ArrayList to an array. However, the issue is that Java converts the array to an array of type objects. I am trying to convert this to an array of type T (generic type). I tried passing in the class type into the constructor of the class using it to cast the array, but I had no luck. My code is below. Any help would be appreciated:

```
public class QuickSelect<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Sort<T> implements Selection<T> {

Class<T> t; // for class type 

QuickSelect(Class<T> t){
    this.t = t;
}

@Override
public T select(T[] data, int n, int k) {

    if(data.length == 0) return null;
    if(k == 1) return data[0];
    if(k >= n || k <=0 ) return null;

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    int pivotPosition = randomGenerator.nextInt(n-1);
    T pivotValue = data[pivotPosition];

    ArrayList<T> lessThanPivot = new ArrayList<T>();
    ArrayList<T> equalToPivot = new ArrayList<T>();
    ArrayList<T> greatThanPivot = new ArrayList<T>();

    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        if(compare(pivotValue, data[i]) < 0) lessThanPivot.add(data[i]);
        else if(compare(pivotValue, data[i]) == 0) equalToPivot.add(data[i]);
        else greatThanPivot.add(data[i]);

    }
    Class<?> tClass = t.getClass();

    if(k <= lessThanPivot.size()) select(lessThanPivot.toArray(), lessThanPivot.size(), k); // this part of the code is where the issue is

    return null; //don't worry about this for now
    }

}
```

Comment: don't worry about the method returning null at some places.. that is on my TODO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of toArray() methods in ArrayList - the one that gets no argumnets, and returns array of Object (that you use) and the other one, that gets as argument the type of array you want to it to return: `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`

so you need to use this one, like this: `lessThanPivot.toArray(data)`

see full javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[]))

Comment: Wow thank you. I can't believe that I didn't know about this method.

Answer (score 2):

If i got your question right i sugget you to use `List.toArray(T[])`

Example `String[]array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);`

Generics are removed when code is compiled, thus the `helper.array` will just return an object[].

I hope this will help.

Comment: Yes thank you Moji. You got my question right and Nir Levy basically gave me the same answer. This works.